# How can I use bootstrap's responsive design without all the repeating code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Perhaps I'm just not seeing something that would easily correct this; however, I find that when I'm using bootstrap's responsive design i tend to repeat code sometimes.  An example of what I'm talking about is shown below.  How can I code this example without repeating code and yet keeping the responsive design?

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 text-left hidden-xs hidden-sm visible-md visible-lg">
                <%= image_tag(@club.logo_image) %>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 text-left hidden-xs visible-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                <%= image_tag(@club.logo_image) %>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 text-center visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                <%= image_tag(@club.logo_image) %>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 text-left hidden-xs hidden-sm visible-md visible-lg">
                <h2><%= @club.name %></h2>
                <h4><%= @club.stadium_name %> - <%= @club.division_and_conference %></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 text-left hidden-xs visible-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                <h2><%= @club.name %></h2>
                <h4><%= @club.stadium_name %> - <%= @club.division_and_conference %></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 text-center visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                <h2><%= @club.name %></h2>
                <h4><%= @club.stadium_name %></h4>
                <h4><%= @club.division_and_conference %></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You could try looking into using a combination of Haml (HTML Abstraction Markup Language) and SASS/SCSS for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With using `SCSS`, you could create a class and extend the other classes.

```
<div class="resp-col-sm-3">
    <%= image_tag(@club.logo_image) %>  
</div>
```

And the class would look something like:

```
.resp-col-sm-3 {
  @extend .col-sm-3;
  @extend .text-left; 
  @extend .hidden-xs;
  @extend .hidden-sm;
  @extend .visible-md;
  @extend .visible-lg;
}
```

Comment: Combining SASS/SCSS with HAML is the way to go in my opinion too. +1

Comment: @kobaltz, I'm coming back to this question.. now this solution solves the repeating class names - but is there any way to eliminating loading the images more than once?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to break down responsiveness behavior into different less file and define class property based on the different media query.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 logo-image">
    <%= image_tag(@club.logo_image) %>  
</div>
```

Then based on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_responsive_utilities.htm

the div for "text-left visible-lg" will become

```
@media screen and (min-width: 922px) {
    .logo-image{
        ...css property values
    }
}
```

the div for "text-center visible-xs" will become

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .logo-image{
        ...css property values
    }
}
```

This is just my personal preference of organizing css styles based on different media query instead of leveraging bootstrap framework.